# Debian web server suddenly is slow and unresponsive

Tags: debian, performance

Until this morning I had a healthy and fast dedicated web server, but suddenly my sites became slow, or even unresponsive. Nothing in the stats below can give me a hint on what is going on. What am I missing?

Also, I have not detected any malware activity

[image: top]

[image: free -m]

[image: iostat]

[image: vmstat 1]

Comment: Nothing in the kernel ring? ("dmesg") Maybe try enabling the mysql slow query log and looking at what your databases are doing? Which processes are doing a lot of I/O? (Try iotop?)

Comment: Ah, and maybe check the the software raid? ("cat /proc/mdstat") If your raid is trying to rebuild, you may be suffering a performance hit.

Comment: Can I get the points for the answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software raid is resyncing, causing high I/O usage. (/proc/mdstat)